# unable to style elements with css flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am having difficult to style the elements inside a `div` in vertically aligned position.
Here is the snippet. I am kind new to CSS flexbox.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700");
#container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
}

#frameworks-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid orangered;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

.framework_rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: orangered;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="frameworks-wrapper">
    <h3>Favorites Web Frameworks ratings</h3>
    <div><span class="framework_rating">3</span>React</div>
    <div><span class="framework_rating">6</span>Blazor</div>
    <div><span class="framework_rating">2</span>Knockout.js</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see the rating and name should be on the same line. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to put a class for the `div` wrapping the elements that you want in the same line:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700");
 
#container{
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
}


#frameworks-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid orangered; 
  background-color: white; 
  color: black;
  border-radius: 25px; 
  font-weight: 800; line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  width:400px;
  height:auto;
}
.framework_rating {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background: orangered;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="frameworks-wrapper">
          <h3>Favorites Web Frameworks ratings</h3> 
          <div class="wrapper"><span class="framework_rating" >3</span>React</div>
          <div class="wrapper"><span class="framework_rating" >6</span>Blazor</div>
          <div class="wrapper"><span class="framework_rating" >2</span>Knockout.js</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps. Best Regards.

Comment: how about horizontal spacing between items on the same line ? Appreciate

Comment: @Xris You could use `justify-content` of the `Flexbox` item positioning properties (Depending on the style of separation that you want) or a simple Padding or Margin will do the job also.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add css on the `div` inside your wrapper:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700");
 
#container{
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
}


#frameworks-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid orangered; 
  background-color: white; 
  color: black;
  border-radius: 25px; 
  font-weight: 800; line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  width:400px;
  height:auto;
}

#frameworks-wrapper>div{
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.framework_rating {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background: orangered;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="frameworks-wrapper">
          <h3>Favorites Web Frameworks ratings</h3> 
          <div><span class="framework_rating" >3</span>React</div>
          <div><span class="framework_rating" >6</span>Blazor</div>
          <div><span class="framework_rating" >2</span>Knockout.js</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: how about horizontal spacing between items on the same line ? Appreciate

Comment: @Xris You can use `margin`. Otherwise, you can use `justify-content` with your wanted `width`. I've updated the code above.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this css on div of frameworks-wrapper id.
you can used flexbox here, which gives you flex layout

```
#frameworks-wrapper>div{
  display: flex;
}
```

For more referance please check this [flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)